# How to make X axis in matplotlib/pylab to NOT sort automatically the values?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, axis

Whenever I plot, the X axis sorts automatically (for example, if i enter values 3, 2, 4, it will automatically sort the X axis from smaller to larger.

How can I do it so the axis remains with the order I input the values i.e 3, 2, 4

```
   import pylab as pl
   data = genfromtxt('myfile.dat')
   pl.axis('auto')
   pl.plot(data[:,1], data[:,0])
```

I found one function, set_autoscalex_on(FALSE) but I'm not sure how to use it or whether it is what I want.
Thanks

Comment: That is what axes are for... Small values are close to the origin and large values are further off. Ask yourself what do you want to plot? Maybe you want to change x and y = f(x) ...

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: I have to plot some data for the last 30 days, and that corrupts the chart, I'll try to add the plot here so you can see

Comment: Do you want two separate lines for `data[:,1]` and `data[:,0]`

Comment: No no, lines are fine, just the axis starts from 1 until 31, whereas I dont want to do that since I'm plotting everyday the last 30 days, that means that the chart should start from 30 days ago until now. So, kinda like this: it should start with January 6, 7, 8, .... 31, 0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 (that is today)

Comment: you should update (edit)  your question if you are talking about datetimes (to make it clear to the readers)

Comment: `set_autoscalex_on(FALSE)` set the authomatic adjustment the axis limits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could provide a dummy x-range, and then override the xtick labels. I do agree with the comments above questioning wether its the best solution, but thats hard to judge without any context.

If you really want to, this might be an option:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,4))

x = [2,4,3,6,1,7]
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

ax[0].plot(x, y)

ax[1].plot(np.arange(len(x)), y)
ax[1].set_xticklabels(x)
```

[image]

edit: If you work with dates, why not plot the real date on the axis (and perhaps format it by the day-of-month if you do want 29 30 1 2 etc on the axis?

Comment: thanks, that proved helpful to me in a situation where I wanted to plot with a categorical x axis (the names of rooms), but I wanted to order it such that the y values (exhibits per room) would be increasing to make it easy on the eye.

Comment: For others reference, if you have a long list for the x axis and need to show all the elements, pls refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131822/how-to-display-all-label-values-in-matlibplo

Comment: In my case the code in the answer didn't work, I was getting the wrong labels in the wrong place. But as suggested by @Kevin, the code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131822/how-to-display-all-label-values-in-matplotlib worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want to set the `xticks`:

```
import pylab as pl
data = genfromtxt('myfile.dat')
pl.axis('auto')
xs = pl.arange(data.shape[0])
pl.plot(xs, data[:,0])
pl.xticks(xs, data[:,1])
```

Working sample:

Another option would be to work with datetimes. If you work with dates, you can use those as input to the plot command.

Working sample:

```
import random
import pylab as plt
import datetime
from matplotlib.dates import  DateFormatter, DayLocator

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(6,8))

# Sample 1: use xticks
days = [29,30,31,1,2,3,4,5]
values = [random.random() for x in days]

xs = range(len(days))

plt.axes(ax[0])
plt.plot(xs, values)
plt.xticks(xs, days)

# Sample 2: Work with dates
date_strings = ["2013-01-30",
                "2013-01-31",
                "2013-02-01",
                "2013-02-02",
                "2013-02-03"]

dates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d") for x in date_strings]
values = [random.random() for x in dates]

plt.axes(ax[1])
plt.plot(dates,values)
ax[1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%b %d"))
ax[1].xaxis.set_major_locator(DayLocator())
plt.show()
```

[image: Sample]

Comment: I'll try this code and get back to you. (though I don't understand it) thanks

Comment: I'll be glad to help you understand it.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot. It worked. though now I got a little issue with the X axis, it got too much crowded :). As you can see http://imgur.com/AD1vbbO If you have any advice on what to search ,say, name of the function, that would be appreciated a lot.

Comment: or to increase the size of the chart so it can fit all date, anyone knows?

Comment: nevermind I just found this way fig = pl.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(18.5,10.5)
fig.savefig('test2png.png',dpi=100)

Comment: You  can control the number of ticks on an axis by specifying an TickLocator. In my code, I use an `DayLocator`. Look at [this page](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/finance_demo.html), there are other sample for locators related to dates.